# How to display only searched string in column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to only display searched string from a table, as example this is my table:

```
Table name: guidelines
id  content 
1   An individual is accused “of” a crime, not “with” or “for” a crime. Accused, often as “the accused”, refers to the individual or individuals standing trial. EXAMPLES: The prosecutor accused the politician of bribery. The accused politician stood trial for bribery. See alleged, charged, suspected.
2   There were a lot of people getting accused on this particular town.
```

If I use search query to search for "accused", it will show the full result:

```
SELECT content FROM "guidelines" WHERE "content" 'ILIKE' '%accused%';
```

Result:

```
content 
An individual is accused “of” a crime, not “with” or “for” a crime. Accused, often as “the accused”, refers to the individual or individuals standing trial. EXAMPLES: The prosecutor accused the politician of bribery. The accused politician stood trial for bribery. See alleged, charged, suspected.

There were a lot of people getting accused on this particular town.
```

How can I only get the first matching string and followed by the data on the column, as example this is my goal:

```
content
Accused, often as “the accused”, refers to th...

accused on this particular to...
```

update: I updated the table and column name to make it better to differentiate table and column

Comment: try `SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(content, 'accused', 1), 'accused', SUBSTRING(content, LOCATE('accused', content) + LENGTH('accused'))) AS content
FROM table_name
WHERE content LIKE '%accused%';`

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL I tried and it gave me error of:
Error in query: ERROR: function substring_index(text, unknown, integer) does not exist

Comment: try `SELECT CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(content FROM 1 FOR POSITION('accused' IN content) - 1),
    'accused',
    SUBSTRING(content FROM POSITION('accused' IN content) + LENGTH('accused'))
) AS content
FROM table_name
WHERE content LIKE '%accused%';`

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL thanks, but I've tried it and it still shows the full result like just like using regular  LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgresql, you can do that by using [position](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-position/) function and [substring](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-substring/) function. see the following query as an example:

```
SELECT
    id,
    substring(content, position ('accused' in content)) as matched
FROM
    guidelines
WHERE
    content LIKE '%accused%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT substring(content from '%#"accused%#"%' for '#') from guidelines;
```

each # is the place holder defined in the last part `for '#'` and need and aditional "

So you have  %  and function will return what is found inside both placeholder. In this case is % or the rest of the string after **accused**